# Wordpress error in capabilities.php

Tags: wordpress

I'm getting the following error on my site and am unable to login to the admin area:

> Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in
>   /wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 127
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 127
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'ai1ec_event_assistant' in
>   /wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 185

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the plugin 'All-in-One Event Calendar' via FTP, then your admin should work. I think it's outdated

Comment: How he will activate this plugin ??

Comment: Okay, so I renamed the All-In_One_Event_calendar folder in wp-content/plugins. This removed the first part of the error message but I still can't login. Is there somewhere elase I need to disable the plugin. Also tried renaming all other plugins but still no change.

Comment: The error message having disabled all-in-one-event-calendar is now:   Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /home/deuxbiers/stoneymiddletonparishcouncil.org.uk/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 125

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/deuxbiers/stoneymiddletonparishcouncil.org.uk/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 125

Comment: Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /home/deuxbiers/stoneymiddletonparishcouncil.org.uk/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 125

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/deuxbiers/stoneymiddletonparishcouncil.org.uk/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 125

Comment: Still got the error. WordPress support have suggested disabling php display_errors which I've asked my host to do but I still can't login.